# How to set Drop down List containing Months to previous month

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have a drop down list which contains months. I have to set it to previous month. I am getting a null reference exception trying to do it in line `DropDownListBM.Items.FindByValue(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString()).Selected = true;`

Given below my code.I am thinking it has something to do with if january is my current month.

```
  DateTime month = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/2000");
                for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
                {
                    DateTime NextMont = month.AddMonths(i);
                    ListItem list = new ListItem();
                    list.Text = NextMont.ToString("MMMM");
                    list.Value = NextMont.Month.ToString();
                    DropDownListBM.Items.Add(list);
                }
DropDownListBM.Items.FindByValue(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString()).Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this:

`DropDownListBM.Items.FindByValue(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString()).Selected = true;`

should be:
`DropDownListBM.Items.FindByValue(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Month.ToString()).Selected = true;`

Comment: Thanks! Do you think this code will work if current month is january? like my dropdownlist will be selected to december?

Comment: Yes, it should (January.AddMonths(-1) should return December). But just set your local computer datetime to January and try!